# How to test wsdl locally

Tags: c#, asp.net, testing, wsdl

I have generated a class using wsdl.exe from the wsdl file.

I inspected the generated code and there is like 3-4 methods available but I guess only by soap protocol(I'm just guessing & probably wrong) which is defined with the attribute above like:

- [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute(etc..)]

Simply, I want to create a dummy class from the wsdl and use its methods.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW, I don't want to use soapui

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using [svcutil.exe instead of wsdl.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650733.aspx)

Using svcutil makes it really easy to make a "dummy" class (which I am reading as a stub or mock) as it generates an interface as well as a proxy.

So, for example,

```
svcutil.exe http://www.restfulwebservices.net/wcf/CurrencyService.svc?wsdl
```

will generate an interface called `ICurrencyService` and a `CurrencyServiceClient`.

Answer (score 1):

The visual studio command prompt has an exe that should allow you to do this.

wcftestclient.exe [service end point address]

hopefuly thats what you mean.